# Safe behaviour using std::optional and conditionals

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a `std::optional<Foo>` object. I want to call on a method of its value (the Foo object), but obviously only if the Foo exists. I can do something like this:

```
std::optional<Foo> test;

/* stuff */

test->method(); //bad! there might not be a Foo in the optional 
              //object depending on what happened in 'stuff'
if(test) {
   if (test->method()) //always valid since 'test' condition was checked
      /* do something */
}

if (test && test->method()) //is this good coding practice? 
    /* do something */
```

**Does including a  condition (test) and a method (test->method()) that depends on this condition (test) to be true in the SAME conditional statement matter?** Is it bad coding etiquette?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [std::optional::value_or](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or) ?

Comment: The string can exist **and** be empty. If you need to check for both, why not.

Comment: No, i am not assigning any value. I simply don't know whether it is good coding practice to put test && test->method() in the same conditional statement when test->method() would be invalid and cause an error if test evaluated false. I know that its optimized so that if 'test' evaluated false, test->method() would not be executed, but still.

Comment: I would say this is opinion based and comes down to readability. The code is guaranteed to be safe because of the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @super this is the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks. I'll still wait to see if somebody else has a different perspective though.

Comment: I agree with @super, this is a subjective question. Personally, I would say there is nothing wrong with the practice. In fact, in the last example `if( test && test->method() )` could be argued to be cleaner since it reduces the amount of nested `if` statements and indentation levels.

Comment: I see this kind of code in C all the time, `if (ptr && ptr->value > 5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/answers. If someone would just post an actual answer I could accept it haha

Comment: This is fine `if(test && test->method())` because the expression after `&&` is not checked if the expression before `&&` is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "Dereference if Not Null" operator. C++ has no such operator.

Some languages do have this operator. This is what the code would look like if C++ adopted the `?.` operator from C#, and then had `std::optional` overload it:

```
std::optional<foo> test = might_return_a_foo();
//If empty, short-circuit and stop. If not null, call method()
test?.method();
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with writing the explicit check, the availability of a proper Dereference-if-Not-Null operator notwithstanding. You don't return an `optional` from a function if you can be confident that the object in question will exist; you'd just return an object and avoid this problem. The fact that the object might not exist is important, and it's probably better that the programmer be forced to write explicit handling for this scenario.

It is worth noting that you can make things a bit more concise though:

```
if(auto opt = might_return_a_foo()) {//opt is deduced to be of type std::optional<foo>
    //This will only evaluate if opt contains a foo
    opt->method();
} else {
    //this will only evaluate if opt did NOT contain a foo
    std::cerr << "No Object to operate on." << std::endl;
}
```

This code handles the check pretty efficiently, and the `optional` object is visible inside the `if` block if and only if the object actually exists; and if it doesn't exist, then you probably don't need the empty `optional` object anyways.